# Import docker compose file in another compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to "import" or link a docker-compose file into another docker-compose file?

Suppose I have two files:

```yaml
# docker-compose-1.yml
services:
    A:
        # config
    B:
        # config
```

```yaml
# docker-compose-2.yml
services:
    C:
        # config
    import: docker-compose-1.yml
```

By running `docker-compose -f docker-compose-2.yml up`, I would like to start containers A, B (specified in the imported file) and C. Is this possible, without having to link both files with the `-f` parameter?

Comment: Is not possible at the moment. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/318

Comment: @EstebanGarcia yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Looks like this is not happening as the issue is almost 5 years old...

Comment: I am having the same requirements as you did now, considering to write a compiler that recursively combines docker compose yamls by walking the directory tree. Did you come up with a solution yet? If not I might share mine, once presentable.

Comment: @jaaq I did, sadly, not, I'd be happy if you could share your solution, once you implement it.

Answer (score 65):

**By extending**

It's possible to extend or use multiple docker-compose files and their services and link them in just one file. You can take a look at [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to understand how is the other usages of multiple compose files. But you can't include the file yet without linking related files together as you mentioned.

Here, I defined a `common-services.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '2'
   services:
      nginx_a:
         image: nginx:latest
         container_name: nginx
         ports:
           - 81:80
           - 1443:443
```

And then, I created a `docker-compose.yml` and included the `common-services.yml` file and its own service as well.

```yaml
services:
   nginx:
      extends:
         file: common-services.yml
         service: nginx_a

      nginx_b:
         image: nginx:latest
            container_name: nginx_b
            volumes:
            ports:
              - 82:80
              - 2443:443
```

**By .env technique**

And if you want to avoid chaining usage of multiple files, there is also [a technique](https://medium.com/@pscheit/docker-compose-advanced-configuration-541356d121de) with `.env` files. I will rewrite the previous example with `.env` technique.

```bash
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=:
COMPOSE_FILE=common-services.yml:docker-compose.yml
```

Let's add another service as an example in the common-services.yml

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  ngin_a:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_a
    ports:
      - 81:80
      - 1443:443

  redis_c:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis_c
    ports:
      - 6381:6380
```

And finally, load all of them in the docker-compose file without even mention to those services.

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
   nginx_b:
     image: nginx:latest
     container_name: nginx_b
     ports:
       - 82:80
       - 2443:443
     env_file:
       - .env
```

In the end, you will have three running services.

Comment: But in the common file, I would still have to declare every single used service, right? Only the configuration will be actually externalized.

Comment: @OndraK. I just updated the answer with .env technique, maybe this one is useful for you. But what you need is not possible without this kind of techniques.

Comment: The `.env` looks like a handy technique, but I am not sure if I understood it correctly. It seems to be used to externalize _service_ related settings. What I actually need is to include compose with multiple services, that are related together, that's why I grouped them in another compose file. The `env_file` is declared under a specific service, so as far as I understood, it can only load properties related to that service. Or am I mistaken? In other words, I don't want to mention the services A and B in the `docker-compose-2.yml` at all.

Comment: @OndraK. hopefully, it's not just about the configuration, I rewrite the previous example with the .env technique and tested it on my laptop. You didn't need to call previous services in the docker-compose file again. As you see I defined the Nginx and Redis service in the common-services file and I just use them inside the docker-compose file without even call those services.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have tried this approach, my `.env` file is loaded, but the included services are not started. Also it seems to me like hacking the `env_file` attribute - especially as it's declared on a service level. What if my included services are completely unrelated to the service where the `env_file` is declared?

Comment: @OndraK. No problem for unrelated services, Here I defined Redis and Nginx services in the common-services which are completely two separated services but both of them are running. Really I don't know what's happening there but it works in the same way you want to use that.

Comment: This is not valid on docker-compose V3 but they have an issue to re-evaluate it -> https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101

Comment: Extending works like a charm on compose 3.9. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, the `.env` trick makes working with multiple `docker-compose-*.yaml` files remarkably more convenient!  Still, I personally find the `.env` file nasty since it is hidden and therefore silently changes otherwise expected, default behavior of `docker-compose`.  Therefore I would always make a note of its usage in the project README.

Comment: with this approach, let's say i have .env.prod file in each of the service folders and i want to pass the respective env files for each service. is there an arguement to do that with the first technique?

Answer (score 21):

Docker Compose top-level element **`include`**

[`include` is available in Docker Compose version **2.20** and later, and Docker Desktop version **4.22** and later.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/include/)

```
include:
  - shared/docker-compose.yaml
  - docker-compose.prod.yaml

services:
  webapp:
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

command will be without mentioning both file as argument **-f**

```
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: Sweet, this seems to be exactly what I needed 4 years ago! :) Will test it out, thanks.

Comment: I really wanted this to work, but for some reason when I include my yaml with service definitions I want in it, then try to run that serviceI just get "no such service: <service_name>

Comment: You can post new question with details and feel free to share link here will take a look into it