# How to run a dockercompose file from another dockercompose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have looked at the docker docs for the answer to this question and I dont see it being laid out simply anywhere. I want to start my app in a docker using `docker-compose.yml` I want that `docker-compose.yml` to start up other containers defined in another `docker-compose.yml` file in a different project.

```
version: '3.4'

#we need network if we want the services to talk to each other
networks:
  services:
    driver: bridge

services:

  jc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
      - PORT=8080
      network: host
    networks:
    - services
    image: jc
    container_name: jc
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

How can I edit this file so that I can run another `docker-compose.yml` file in a different file path when I run this `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: You can get an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650342/import-docker-compose-file-in-another-compose-file/55652819 
You can extend the file and achieve this

Comment: @SriniM I am getting an error Unsupported config option for services.jc: 'extends'... Ive googled after this error and seems like it is not supported. Do you know anything about this? I am using docker-compose 1.24,1 Thanks.

Comment: Did you try  "Use docker-compose config to generate a configuration with all extends options resolved, and deploy from that" . There are chances your compose version is not supporting extends. but i found that you can generate the compose file with all your extend configuration using docker-compose config. Try and let us know

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After trying the to use the extends option of the docker-compose file and differing variations of its usage I consistently received an error indicating that extends is not supported even after updating to the latest docker version. I did however solve the problem by running this command.

`docker-compose -f /path/to/other/docker-compose-file/docker-compose.yml up`

I was sure that I had to add something to the docker-compose file so I overlooked this in the docs. But you can read more about it here. 
[docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack but you can add another container that starts docker compose with another docker-compose file.
for example:

Docker file for the starter container:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN mkdir -p /compose
WORKDIR /compose
CMD ["docker-compose", "up", "-d"]
```

The main docker compose file (starts a redis server and the starter container). note the compose binary, docker socket and another docker-compose.yml file are mounted into the starter container:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  from-main-compose:
    image: redis:3

  starter:
    image: starter:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /usr/local/bin/docker-compose:/usr/local/bin/docker-compose:ro
      - /home/shay/source/composeFromContainer/another-compose/docker-compose.yml:/compose/docker-compose.yml:ro
```

Second docker compose file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  redis-from-container:
    image: redis:3
```

The result is this:

```
b1faa975df49        redis:3             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        6379/tcp            compose_redis-from-container_1
7edca79d3d99        redis:3             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        6379/tcp            composefromcontainer_from-main-compose_1
```

Note that if using this hack as it is the services will be placed on different networks so this might need to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Nice option as a hack. But With docker you can extend compose files. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650342/import-docker-compose-file-in-another-compose-file/55652819

Comment: You are right. extending the compose file is a better option. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also prefer a non hack solution. I get an error `Unsupported config option for services.jc: 'extends'` ... I've also read that extends is not supported. Is this true? I am using docker-compose 1.24,1

Comment: @Dan Did you try "Use docker-compose config to generate a configuration with all extends options resolved, and deploy from that" . There are chances your compose version is not supporting extends. but i found that you can generate the compose file with all your extend configuration using docker-compose config. Try and let us know

Comment: Hi @SriniM if I do the `docker-compose config` with the extends attribute in the file I get the same error. If I do it without that attribute then I just get an output that resembles my docker-compose file. I tried putting that output in the docker-compose file and trying to build, and compose-up but I get the same error. Should I change my docker-compose version? I believe that my current version 1.24.1 should support this feature. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can upgrade the version to the recent one and try.